# Call a function from a parent scope to a directive without passing a parameter map every time?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my directive

```
function myDirective() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "path/file.html",
        scope: {
            functionInParentScope: "&",
        },
    };
    return directive;
}
```

This is the function in the parent scope

```
$scope.functionInParentScope = (part, parts) ->
    return (part & parts) > 0
```

This is the directive element in the parent template

```
<my-directive
    function-in-parent-scope"functionInParentScope(part, parts)">
</my-directive>
```

This is a call to the function from within the directive:

```
functionInParentScope({part: a, parts: b})
```

How can I call the function in the parent scope without having to provide a parameter map every time?

I want to be able to just write `functionInParentScope(a, b)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to have this mapping anyway. What you can however do is to add some sugar to it so that you don't have to do it *in template* all the time.

So basically what I mean is that you can decorate original `functionInParentScope` binding with new version of it. Something like this:

```
function myDirective() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "path/file.html",
        scope: {
            functionInParentScope: "&",
        },
        link: function(scope) {
            scope.functionInParentScope = function(original) {
                return function(a, b) {
                    return original({ part: a, parts: b});
                };
            }(scope.functionInParentScope);
        }
    };
    return directive;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify the `scope` key in your directive's object, the directive will by default use the parent scope. So just remove that `scope` key and call those methods inside your directive:

```
$scope.functionInParentScope();
```